# How to set up startup configuration for Azure AD multiple client application accessing single ASP.NET Core Web API for authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which can be accessed by many client applications. I want to authenticate all client applications. All client application have different client ID under same tenant. How to do this?

This is my `appsettings.json` file

[image]

And here is my `Startup.cs` file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Essilor.Common.AwsMfaHelper.ProfileHelper.UseProfile("ride-dev", true);
    InitializeEnvironment();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddAuthZClient();

    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAWSService<Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3>();

    RegisterServices(services);

    services.AddMvcCore();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuditTrailAttribute));
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current scenario, this is similar to the concept of ApiKey, I modified the following sample code based on the code tested in my previous answer, I hope it will be useful to you.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SecuringWebApiUsingClient_ID.Middleware
{
public class Client_IDMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private const string APIKEYNAME = "ApiKey";
    public Client_IDMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Client_ID, out var extractedClient_ID))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Client ID was not provided. (Using Client_IDMiddleware) ");
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(Client_IDs);

        if (!Client_IDs.Equals(extractedClient_ID))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized client. (Using Client_IDMiddleware)");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
}
```

For more details, pls check below thread.

[ASP.NET core - simple API key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70287196/7687666)